# Set toggle button on App headline

Tags: android, togglebutton

> In my application i want to add toggle button right side of the Application-name (ie)Right side of BluetoothTextMessaging 
>   Please help me thanks...
>   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you:

**Try this:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.addSubMenu(0, 1, 1, " Button ").setIcon(R.drawable.file_icon)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);;

        return true;
    }
```

**And you can access that button using following code & write logic what to perform on click of that button inside the following code :**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case 1: {
                             // Your Logic
                           break;
                        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you're searching for is called an options menu. On **Android 3.0+ it is supported**. This is how Google's own tutorial describes it:

- If you've developed your application for **Android 2.3.x (API level 10)**
  or lower, the contents of your options menu appear at the bottom of
  the screen when the user presses the Menu button, as shown in figure
  When opened, the first visible portion is the icon menu, which holds up to six menu items. If your menu includes more than six
  items, Android places the sixth item and the rest into the overflow
  menu, which the user can open by selecting More.
- If you've developed your application for **Android 3.0 (API level 11)**
  and higher, items from the options menu are available in the action
  bar. By default, the system places all items in the action overflow,
  which the user can reveal with the action overflow icon on the right
  side of the action bar (or by pressing the device Menu button, if
  available). To enable quick access to important actions, you can
  promote a few items to appear in the action bar by adding
  `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to the corresponding  elements

**Follow this link:** ([Menu tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)) to get to the tutorial.

I can provide code snippets, however the ones on the website are much better :-)

Comment: i want add toggle button